# Why don't network-activated plugins appear in Wordpress Mutisite child page menu?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am running WordPress 4.8 and am using Multisite with just a main page and a child page.

I installed plugins on my main site and they have been network-activated in the plugin menu. Yet, they do not appear in the child page plugin menu.

Even when I installed a new plugin and network-activated it upon installation, it did not appear in the plugin menu on the child page.

In the settings, I have checked the box for plugins in Menu>menu settings>enable administration menus.

For people having similar problems, I found a [blogpost](http://chrislema.com/plugins-in-wordpress-multisite/), but it did not help me

I would appreciate help as I didn't find a lot of material on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by child page? If you mean that network activated plugins are not visible by site administrators on the Plugins admin page of their site, this is normal.

Network activated plugins cannot be controlled by site administrators, so no need to see them. If you visit the same page logged-in as Super Administrator though, you will see them, and it will say under them: Network Active.

Comment: I logged in as super administrator and it still doesn't appear on the plugin admin page. In addition, the activated plugins weren't working.

Comment: @AvrahamLifshitz That is a problem then. Try deactivating all plugins, and then just activate one plugin like akismet for example to test how it works. Some of the plugins you are using might be causing this issue. Especially if you have a plugin that changes other plugin behavior.

Comment: HIi @Nikolay - I network deactivated all the plugins, and even deactivated all plugins on the main site, but the plugins still don't appear on the subdomain plugin admin page. (So I can't even activate the plugins for the subdomain). How can I activate the other plugins on the subdomain site? Many thanks

Comment: @AvrahamLifshitz Probably then some kind of server related issue with access to the plugins folder or something... Maybe file permissions of plugins folder or some .htaccess file blocks something for the subdomains.